# Refresh window.rootViewController.view contents

Tags: ios, rotation, mbprogresshud

I am building an app in which I use **MBProgressHUD** library as an activity indicator. I attach the HUD to **self.view.window.rootViewController.view** . Everything works fine but when I rotate the device, the HUD (UIActivityIndicator) is overlapped by the other screen items and it looks as if HUD is in background of the view. Does any one has any idea how to deal with this issue? has any one used MBProgressHUB library and faced similar issues?

P.S I have to attach HUD to self.view.window.rootViewController.view  only.

Comment: If you attach the HUD to rootviewController, and if you present a view controller then the HUD will be hidden by the new viewcontroller.

Comment: @MidhunMP It seems the problem is what you pointed out.How do I solve this issue then?How do I bring it in front of new viewcontroller? Or how to do I assign my HUD to new viewcontroller on rotation?

Comment: In `MBProgressHUD` there is an option to add the HUD to window. I think adding HUD to window will solve the issue.

Comment: @MidhunMP. I could solve it using "adding HUD to window". Thank you.

Comment: Happy to know that you fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your view. Add this code;

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```